# Why $\mathbb E\Big(\big(X-\mathbb E(X|Y )\big)^2\Big)\le 2\mathbb E\left(X^2\right)$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Given $\mathbb E\left(X^2\right) \lt \infty $, why
$$\mathbb E\Big(\big(X -\mathbb E(X \mid Y )\big)^2\Big) \leq 2\mathbb E\left(X^2\right) \lt \infty  \;\text?$$

Comment: Not sure about the prefactor $2$, but we even have a better version: $$E(X^2)=E\left((X-E(X\mid Y))^2\right)+E\left((E(X\mid Y))^2\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for helping, i find this on a book, this inquality was referenced when trying to prove another theorem. But I have problem understanding your equality, too.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you! I found the theorem for the equality you wrote. this clearly implies the inequality i asked.